# Unable to get correct input value on click of browser return button?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have multiple form creating for various condition but submit one at a time will take to another page. if i come back from that all my form with conditioned value taking same value on return to this page. Here is my code

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url($turl.'/fixture_result/3'); ?>" method="post">
<!-- CSRF NAME -->
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
<!-- END OF CSRF  -->
<input type="hidden" name="grouptab" value="{{groupNameArry[index3]}}">
<input type="hidden" name="edit1" value="1">
<?php if($permission == 1 || $permission == 2) { ?>
<input type="submit" value="Edit Tournament"class="btn-theme theme-btn-cancel">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

where `{{groupNameArray}}` is angular calculated value. groupNameArry contains A to G and index3 is an itrating value. while submitting this form goes to another page and if from there if i click back button it comes back to the page but this time all the grouptabl input contains "A";

Please Help ? Only on Page Refresh i got my values back.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  How is angular "calculating" this array?  Does it need to be recalculated when you come back to the route?  How are your routes defined for these components?  This isn't enough code or information to help you with this problem.

Comment: a plnkr would be helpful

Comment: @instantaphex there is a loop on its parent which contains index3

Comment: it is the problem regarding post item in cache. Please let me know how could i resolve them while on clicking of back button.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

By using `autocomplete="off"` on form. my problem get resolved.

here is the fixed code

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url($turl.'/fixture_result/3'); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<!-- CSRF NAME -->
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
<!-- END OF CSRF  -->
<input type="hidden" name="grouptab" value="{{groupNameArry[index3]}}">
<input type="hidden" name="edit1" value="1">
<?php if($permission == 1 || $permission == 2) { ?>
<input type="submit" value="Edit Tournament"class="btn-theme theme-btn-cancel">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```